# Type Hints Don't Evaluate In Decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

Given

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass
```

If I define a new `ACallback` type that takes an instance of `A`

```
from typing import Callable

ACallback = Callable[[A], None]
```

And define a function that takes an instance of `B`

```
def b_callback(b: B):
    pass
```

If I try to use `b_callback` where `ACallback` is expected, I get type hint warnings - as expected.

```
def test(callback: ACallback):
    pass


test(the_callback)  # <-- "Expected type '(A) -> None', got '(b: B) -> None` instead
```

However, if I create a decorator that takes an `ACallback`

```
def test2(callback: ACallback):
    def decorate(f):
        def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return new_f
    return decorate
```

And pass a function that doesn't match

```
@test2(the_callback)  # <-- No type hint errors
def decorator_test():
    pass
```

I don't see any type hint warnings.

**Question: Is the lack of type hint warnings due to...**

- Type hint mistakes?
- Python type hint limitations?
- PyCharm type hint limitations?
- Something else?

Comment: What are you using to do type analysis? PyCharm built-in handling? mypy seems to handle decorators fine in my tests so far.

Comment: It's a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27142)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (or "lack of a feature") in PyCharm. I tried this program:

```
import typing

ACallback = typing.Callable[[int], None]

def test2(callback: ACallback):
    def decorate(f):
        def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return new_f
    return decorate


def foo(s: str):
    pass


test2(foo)


@test2(foo)
def bar():
    pass
```

with latest version of `mypy`, and the results were

```
decorated.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "test2" has incompatible type "Callable[[str], Any]"; expected "Callable[[int], None]"
decorated.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "test2" has incompatible type "Callable[[str], Any]"; expected "Callable[[int], None]"
```

i.e. both uses resulted in an error.

---

If you want to use it with PyCharm, are at least 2 different plugins for PyCharm integration; one named [mypy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11086-mypy), and the other by [Dropbox](https://github.com/dropbox/mypy-PyCharm-plugin), which is [not available via JetBrains repository](https://github.com/dropbox/mypy-PyCharm-plugin/issues/7).

I'd consider the DropBox one the "official mypy-endorsed plugin" in the sense that [all the key mypy/Python type hinting people are employed by Dropbox](http://mypy-lang.org/about.html)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a comment for future readers re the plugins:
`mypy` plugin is broken as of latest PyCharm release (183.4)
the dropbox plugin doesn't actually enhance visual built-in type hints, just provides a way of running mypy more easily